# .htaccess redirecting from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

This may have been asked before but I can't find an answer.

I have recently purchased an SSL certificate and I need help setting up the **.htaccess** file.

I am using the MVC design pattern so every page goes though index.php

This is my current .htaccess configuration and all pages go through https

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have read that using https on the whole site adds overheads. Would it be possible to add rules for specific pages such as login/register/forgot password that would redirect to https instead of http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect specific pages to `https`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# specific pages to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(login|register|forgotPassword) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# all other pages to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(login|register|forgotPassword) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. If i needed to add more pages ,is it just add them to RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(login|register|forgotPassword) [NC]

Comment: Yes that's right, you can add more pages like that.

Comment: Last question. How would i add admin/news or something like that?

Comment: Use `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(login|register|forgotPassword|admin/news) [NC] `